# Display products in information tab product product page

Tags: product, xml

In Magento's 1.9 theme you get tabs with information on the product page. I want one tab to display custom chosen products and I want below the tabs the related products.

I've added a couple of tabs before and have the template file ready, but I can't get the file to display.

**Catalog.xml**

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"> 
    <alias>onderhoudsmiddelen</alias>
    <title>Onderhoudsmiddelen</title>  
    <block>catalog/product_list_related</block> // Also changed it to <block>catalog/product_list</block> But that displays an error
    <template>catalog/product/view/middelen.phtml</template>
</action>
```

Comment: what you mean by custom chosen products ?

Comment: @Amit Bera i'm sorry, I phrased that wrong, I want products from a specif category

Answer (score 1):

**alias** should `unique for each tab`.

block type `catalog/product_view`  is  for getting current product page.
Also you can template file as per requirement.

On template phtml file you need custom code getting category  product